# Cannot access Chrome page information dialog box

Tags: google-chrome

I want to control some of the behaviors/permissions for a page, with examples such as JavaScript, Flash, or notifications, but every time I try to click the favicon (or lack of one; the 'i' letter inside of a circle symbol is there) on [a certain page](http://alttp.challonge.com/rando2017), it seems to think I want to drag and drop the page address somewhere, instead of bringing up that familiar Chrome page information box.

Right now it only happens on that 1 site.

On this site, the "Secure" text with lock icon to the left of that word appears, and clicking that brings the expected results as I just mentioned.

I vaguely maybe remember this being available in the right-click context menu, or in the properties/browser menu in the top-right corner, or pressing the Cmd+i key combination like similar function in other Mac-based applications, for example, Finder opens more verbose file/folder/item information in a separate window.

Chrome 57 on MacOS 10.12.3.

Links:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/3vltma/where_has_view_page_info_gone_after_a_right_click/
- http://support.proboards.com/thread/593471/view-page-info-chrome

and probably more.

Comment: You do know that websites use JavaScript. So you can't be sure what the page is doing, what the programmer has tried to "block" you from doing or any other "stuff" that might be doing. You say it's this page for now. I'd just leave it at that and understand that all programmers aren't equal, nor are developers of websites. Also, developers are more aware of what people are doing and don't particularly care at one spectrum, and others really hide their code in ways that can't be pried and pulled at. Realized this too.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are saying, but it seems unrelated.  Are you claiming some JavaScript on the page could have altered the behavior of the Google Chrome browser to not display the page information box that is usually accessed across pages, especially for security concerns, and for an element that does not exist in the page context?  I seriously doubt that.

Comment: I'm familiar with old or current methods of preventing/changing the status text that usually appears on hover, sneaking in text when you execute a clipboard copy command, and disabling the right-click context menu.  Similar to these points, web browsers may have taken away, or restricted some of these abilities for the web pages JavaScript to control in the name of securing casual and more users, another example in the HTML5 file blob/system access, clipboard ability, notifications, etc.  This seems like something they would want to retain and protect from the page as well.

Comment: Yes, exactly to your first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well on version 74 now and it works better, coming up every time I click on the lock icon in the address bar for example.  It took a while to fix, maybe around 62-66?